# Set ascendnig X axis in a QlikView chart

Tags: qlikview

I have a qlikview chart where the dimension is  the week of a date.
So i get a groupped sum of the values for weeks.

Its good but when its start from the middle of the year it will start ascending e.g.:

```
y->2    5  2
x->22  23 24 etc
```

but i want:

```
y->2 5 2
x->1 2 3
```

But I tried to change dimension somehow but all faild, I tried at the sort tab some expression or the layout but i simply cant find to to replace the x-axis values.

So now the dimension (x) is Calender_Week of the date. but it returns 0-52 the week of the year.
But I dont want to show this 0-52 I want a static numbers.

```
If week 26-32 then 1-2-3-4-5-6-7
If week 12-13 then 1-2
If week 51-52-01-02 then 1-2-3-4
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you cannot sort the values correctly is because the week number is just a value between 1 and 53. You cannot specify a sort order since there is no way of telling which year the week number belongs to.

However, there is a way to resolve this. In the following example, let's assume that I have my data table `MyData` defined as follows:

```
MyData:
LOAD 
    * 
INLINE [
    CalendarDate, Result
    15/12/2014, 5
    16/12/2014, 6
    22/12/2014, 10
    29/12/2014, 20
    30/12/2014, 30
    05/01/2015, 20
];
```

I have another table which loads from `MyData` and derives the week number:

```
MyChartData:
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    WeekNumber,
    Sum(Result) as Result
GROUP BY WeekNumber;
LOAD
    Week(date#(CalendarDate,'DD/MM/YYYY')) as WeekNumber,
    Result
RESIDENT MyData;

DROP TABLE MyData;
```

If I chart these data I have the problem of sorting (at first glance it seems okay, but in this instance week 1 should come *after* week 52):

[image: QlikView Chart with axis sorting problem]

Now, to solve this we need another way to sort the data but still keep it grouped at a weekly level. As I have the original calendar date, I can create a new field which does just that: a concatenation of week number and year (i.e. YYYYWW):

```
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    WeekNumber,
    YearWeek,
    Sum(Result) as Result
GROUP BY WeekNumber, YearWeek;
LOAD
    WeekNumber,
    (WeekYear * 100 + WeekNumber) as YearWeek,
    Result;   
LOAD
    Week(date#(CalendarDate,'DD/MM/YYYY')) as WeekNumber,
    WeekYear(date#(CalendarDate,'DD/MM/YYYY')) as WeekYear,
    Result
RESIDENT MyData;
```

If I then swap out `WeekNumber` from my chart and replace it with `WeekYear` then things are looking better:

[image: A better looking chart with correct axis sorting]

**Edit - now to relabel the dimension values**

To relabel the `YearWeek` values so that they are just shown as an relative index (or "column" number), we can use a calculated dimension and utilise the `aggr` function as follows:

```
=aggr(RowNo(), YearWeek)
```

This then results in a chart as follows:

[image: A QlikView chart with relative column indexing]

The advantage to this method is that whichever selections you make in your QlikView document, the relative index will remain contiguous even though the underlying data could be discontinuous. Furthermore this does not hard-code the index into the data model.

Comment: My queastion is actually is to eg: change your last chart 
x-axis labes to 1 2 3 4 5 
insted of 51 52 01 02

Comment: Thanks, that was i looking for aggre and rownumbut i coudnt use it properly.